# Resolve an object fields's union type after implementation

Tags: typescript

## Intro

I have a type called `TypeWithDynamicValue`. The `value` of this type is restricted by the union `string | boolean | number`.

### Goal

When implementing `TypeWithDynamicValue`, I want the type of `value` to be resolved so that it is no longer the union type. Also, I don't want a developer to have to use a generic to determine the type of `value` <strike>or to use `satisfies`</strike> when declaring an implementation of `TypeWithDynamicValue`.

```
type TypeWithDynamicValue = {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
  value: string | boolean | number;
}

const implementation: TypeWithDynamicValue = {
  foo: 'fizz',
  bar: false,
  value: 59
};
type ValueTypeResult = typeof implementation.value; // is still "string | boolean | number" instead of "number"
```

## Attempt

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-xjsoqh?file=index.ts).

I changed the type to what is below and have a function `someFunction` that returns `MyInterface` which shares properties with `TypeWithDynamicValue` except for `valueWithStrictType`, which is `value` but with its type deciphered from the `param1`.

```
// types.ts
export type TypeWithDynamicValue = {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
} & (
  | {
      value: string;
    }
  | {
      value: number;
    }
  | {
      value: boolean;
    }
);
// function.ts
export function someFunction<T extends TypeWithDynamicValue>(param1: T): MyInterface<T['value']> {
  return {
    foo: param1.foo,
    bar: param1.bar,
    valueWithStrictType: param1.value
  }
}
```

## Problems

*This works!*

*Except* it [breaks](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56964) when you import the implementation of `TypeWithDynamicValue` compared to when its declared locally (see index.ts). This is because within the same file, we see the control-flow-analyzed type of a value, but outside the file, it's always the declared type from the type annotation.

## Suggestions

Perhaps using [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) with `TypeWithDynamicValue` could help?

Comment: "I don't want ... to use `satisfies` when declaring an implementation of `TypeWithDynamicValue`". Why? At some point, "I don't want to do the things that are known to work" means the answer here is more likely to look like "no, sorry". Can you explain why you need to declare a variable's type and then have the declared type of it be different? I think that is essentially impossible. You could copy the variable to a new one and let the compiler infer its type instead of annotating, and then export *that* like [this](//tsplay.dev/W4JDXN). But I don't know if that meets your needs. Thoughts?

Comment: Originally, I wanted to avoid generics and `satisfies` because all developers (of varying skill levels) in my company will be implementing many instances of `TypeWithDynamicValue` often and so I wanted the DX to be very simple. The copy / export strategy is interesting, but of course adds some overhead. I'm thinking `satisfies` is probably my best bet here.

Comment: So what should we do for an answer here? Do you want to edit the question to remove the bit about `satisfies`? Or, write your own answer?

Comment: I answered my question and added a strikethrough over where I requested to not use `satisfies`. Thank you for your comments, they helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript's control flow analyzer only narrows a union type when such variables are declared in the same file as they're used (rather than being imported). Hence, the most concise solution is to use `satisfies` like so:

```
// consts.ts
export const implementation = {
  foo: 'fizz',
  bar: false,
  value: 59
} satisfies TypeWithDynamicValue;

// index.ts
import { implementation } from './consts.ts';
type ValueTypeResult = typeof implementation.value // returns 'number'
```